(Photoshop) How do I convert point tool multiple anchor points at the same time?
How do I convert point tool multiple anchor points at the same time in Photoshop?

I'm not sure you can. One area where Illustrator may be preferable for vectors.

You can't. There's no such functionality, maybe there's a script somewhere that could do it.  For something like this, it's probably better to use an actual vector image editor - both Illustrator and Inkscape (which is free) allow multiple anchor/node selection and conversion to corner/curve points all in one go.
